# How to set up authorized keys for dropbear local to openssh remote

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, dropbear

I have a local machine running dropbear and I want to connect to a remote host running openssh without having to type the password every time.

I have found *lots* of documentation on how to do the reverse, and it seems easy because dropbear does support `/etc/dropbear/authorized_keys`. However what I want does not seem nearly as easy and I can't find any documentation on this.

I have tried copying `/etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key` to the remote hosts `.ssh/authorized_keys` but that didn't work. So either I didn't do it right (very possible), or it can't be done that way.

I have tried generating keys on the remote host and then copying them into local's `.ssh/`, and adding the public to remote's `.ssh/authorized_keys` but that didn't work either.

I haven't been able to think of anything else to try, so I figured I'd try to ask someone more experienced than me.

Answer (score 1):

A few things unclear from your question:

- `dbclient` is the `dropbear` client program
- `dropbear`/`dbclient` cannot natively read OpenSSH private key files so they have to be created using `dropbearkey` or converted using `dropbearconvert`

That said here is how to make a private key on the dropbear **client machine** and append the public key to the authorized_keys file on the OpenSSH **server host**.

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
dropbearkey -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/id_dropbear # this creates a private key in the default location for dbclient
#substitute the username and host on the following line and please note the use of both single quotes (') and back ticks (`)
dbclient username@host 'mkdir ~/.ssh; echo '`dropbearkey -y -f ~.ssh/id_dropbear | grep ssh `'>> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; chmod 600 ~./ssh/authorized_keys'  # accept the hostkey and login using your password. You should be returned to the client prompt
dbclient username@host # client should automatically use the id_dropbear file for key authentication.
```

I tested this all on the two Debian 11 (bullseye) VMs, but it should work for any Linux OS using a standard-ish dropbear package.

Edit: Just a note to add that private keys should always be generated on the local machine and public keys copied to a remote. Private keys off of the local host are nearly always a security risk (except maybe encrypted backups).